# Sending an email using a dataset in SAS

Tags: loops, email, sas, dataset

I am new to SAS. I have a dataset and I need to create multiple emails from this dataset with csv attachments.

Here is the set:

```
owner_id, owner_name, owner_email, data_name, data_value
1, Andrew, andrew@.com, Awesome Data Name 1, 33
1, Andrew, andrew@.com, Awesome Data Name 2, 44
1, Andrew, andrew@.com, Awesome Data Name 3, 55
2, Bill, bill@.com, Awesome Data Name 4, 66
2, Bill, bill@.com, Awesome Data Name 5, 77
2, Bill, bill@.com, Awesome Data Name 6, 88
3, Sam, sam@.com, Awesome Data Name 7, 99
```

Based on this set, I need to send 3 emails with the following attachments:

**EMAIL TO:** andrew@.com

> attachment: file_for_owner_1.csv

```
data_name, data_value
Awesome Data Name 1, 33
Awesome Data Name 2, 44
Awesome Data Name 3, 55
```

**EMAIL TO:** bill@.com

> attachment:file_for_owner_2.csv

```
data_name, data_value
Awesome Data Name 4, 66
Awesome Data Name 5, 77
Awesome Data Name 6, 88
```

**EMAIL TO:**  sam@.com

> attachment: file_for_owner_3.csv

```
data_name, data_value 
Awesome Data Name 7, 99
```

I know that in JAVA, I would create a loop within a loop and would build a List of objects based on the Class. In SAS, I don't know how to do it. I tried doing this as a first, but it does not work so I need to learn how to address this kind of loops in SAS, but I am stuck. Please advise.

```
data notification_list;
filename mymail email (owner_email)
   subject="Here is your email";

   file mymail;
   put "Hello, &owner_name. Please send us your report";
   put "Metric ID:" data_name ;
   put "Reporting Period:" data_value ;   
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

You use PUT statement email directives.

http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lestmtsref/69738/HTML/default/viewer.htm#n0ig2krarrz6vtn1aw9zzvtez4qo.htm